# Maximize an application with known PID from CLI

Tags: command-line, maximized

I need to maximize the window of an application when it's minimized using the command line only..

So how to do that knowing the process ID.

When working on the `wmctrl` command i got the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x6718
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

Comment: Please add the outout of `wmctrl -lp` and the **exact** command you use to raise the window to your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search --pid YOUR_PID_HERE | tail -1`
```

xdootool reports a quite a few window id-s when looking up by pid, so I "tailed" the output to only get the last window id from the output. For me it worked well with both Firefox and gnome-calculator. If xdotool only reports one window id for your pid then the tail pipe is of course unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `wmctrl` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/wmctrl.1.html)) to manipulate windows from the command line.

1. Install the programm using `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` or any other package manager you feel comfortable with.
2. Get the window ID belonging to your PID. `wmctrl -lp` will list all existing windows with their window ID in the first and the PID in the second column of the output.
3. Raise the window with `wmctrl -iR <window ID>` or `wmctrl -ia <window ID>`, depending on whether you want to switch to its desktop or move it to the current one.

Comment: we have install "wmctrl" or its installed by default??

Comment: `wmctrl` is available in the package **wmctrl**. Added that to my answer.

Comment: X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x6718
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11

Comment: i just know this command but it's not working for that i asked if there's a solution or other command

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
awk '$3 == 17213 {print $1}' <(wmctrl -lp) | xargs -i% sh -c "xwit -id % -pop -raise; wmctrl -i -r % -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
```

You'll need to change the ID in the `awk` statement but that will maximise and to activate the window. You'll also need to install `xwit` (`sudo apt-get install xwit`) for the un-minimisation to work.

---

The reason this is so complicated is because no one tool does everything you need and those that are slightly capable, have terminal issues:

- `xdotool` can't look up by PID (despite that being an advertised feature)
- `wmctrl` doesn't know how to minimise and maximise things
- `xwit` can't *change* window hints but it can un-minimise things

Ideally this is something you should be able to do with just `xdotool` or `wmctrl` but their PID look-ups don't work or exist respectively.

Comment: I tried it, Nothing happens... The window stilled minimized

Comment: @maythux Updated.

Comment: Still not working